# Font in 'GraphicsPath.AddString' is smaller than usual font

Tags: c#, graphics, fonts, path, gdi

For some reason if I add a string to **GraphicsPath** using **AddString** the font is going to be smaller than it looks like in the Font Dialog.

```
  SizeF sz = g.MeasureString(Text, new Font(Font.FontFamily, (int)(Font.Size - (Font.Size / 7)), Font.Style), new PointF(0, 0), StringFormat.GenericDefault);

  this.Size = new Size((int)sz.Width, (int)sz.Height);
  //These are not the same
  fontpath.AddString(this.Text, this.Font.FontFamily,(int)this.Font.Style, this.Font.Size, new Point(0, 0),StringFormat.GenericDefault);
```

*Does anyone know why it might be doing that?*

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Assuming your Font.Size's unit is `Point`, you should convert the size that you passed to `AddString` to emSize (The height of the em square box that bounds the character).

```
float emSize = graphics.DpiY * font.Size / 72;
```

Comment: Why assume the point unit when there is `Font.SizeInPoints`? Also what does "convert to emSize" mean? Em size is not a unit. Why not tell people that `AddString` expects the pixel unit (which I assume because of your formula that converts points to pixels)?

Comment: Clarifying on the above comment, `emSize` is provided here because that is the "unit" expected as an argument to `Path::AddString()`.  "em" is a unit in typography referring to a size relative to a capital "M". See [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Em_(typography)) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

```
float emSize = graphics.DpiY * font.SizeInPoints / 72;
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on how your code answers the question?